# Wifi connection

Tags: wireless, toshiba-satellite

I have a Toshiba Satellite s50d-A-10f and have installed Ubuntu on it. But I can not connect to Wi-Fi Networks although it is able to recognize that there are open networks. It keeps asking me for the password and I am putting the correct password but it still wont go through. The laptop uses an Atheros AR956x wireless adapter.

Comment: Is your driver _ath9k_? Please check from the terminal: lsmod  Welcome to askubuntu!

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Ethernet cable, please connect to your modem with it. In order to find the IP address of your modem, please open up a terminal and enter `route -n` and then look for an entry in the column `Gateway`. You can then open up a browser and navigate to the modem's settings and

1. Check whether the password is indeed the one you are typing.
2. Check whether you have selected the right type of security type.

**EDIT**:

You can always do that procedure with another PC, given that it is connected to the internet through that modem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you sure you have a correct password?

Maybe you can turn on a access point via your phone and set a simple password like 12345678 and see if you can connect the phone's access point.

I think you may have a wrong password or just type it wrong.